# Create new T[] in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, arrays, generics

How can I do the same as the following in VB.NET

```cs
List<T[]> result = new List<T[]>();

// single combination
if (k == 0)
{
   result.Add(new T[0]); // T is function type argument of generic function
```

How can I write the last line above in VB.NET?

I tried:

```vb
result.Add(New T(0)) 'doesn't work!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
result.Add(New T(0) {})
```

Comment: so what functionality do the curly braces have in this case?

Comment: Sorry, it should be New T(-1) {}. The value isn't the array length in VB, but the upper bound. The curly braces tell the VB compiler it is an array, and it can be used to place the elements of the array, eg: New T(1) {New T(), New T()}

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following:

```
    Dim A(0) As T                   ' Length = 1
    Dim B As T() = New T(0) {}      ' Length = 1
    Dim C As T() = New T() {}       ' Length = 0
    Dim D As T() = New T(-1) {}     ' Length = 0
    Dim E(-1) As T                  ' Length = 0
    Dim F As T() = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(T), 0)  ' Length = 0
```

So I recommend the 3rd option at it is the cleanest.